# Access INSERT INTO - to few parameters. expected 2

Tags: vba, ms-access, insert-query

Good afternoon,

I'm having a problem with a INSERT statement in VBA.
Everytime I'm trying to insert a new record to the table through input from the form I'm getting a error.

> Run-time error '3061':
>   Too few parameters. Expected 2.

And this is the VBA behind it.

```
Private Sub Command242_Click()
Dim dbs As Database

' Modify this line to include the path to Northwind
' on your computer.
Set dbs = CurrentDb

'Testing purpose
Me.cbPenalty1 = 0
Me.cbOwnGoal1 = 0
' Create a new record in the tblMatchPlayer table.
' Query saved the player who scored with values in a new row, linked with MatchID & PlayerID.

'Testing purpose MsgBox - DELETE WHEN WORKS!!
MsgBox " INSERT INTO tblMatchPlayer " _
        & "(MatchID, PlayerID, SubstituteID, PositionID, Surname, ScoreTime, RedCards, YellowCards, Substitude, Penalty, OwnGoal, Assist) VALUES " _
        & "(" & Me.MatchID & ", '', '', '', " & Me.cmScoreName1 & ", " & Me.tbScoreTime1 & ", '', '', '', " & Me.cbPenalty1 & ", " & Me.cbOwnGoal1 & ", " & Me.cmAssist1 & ");", vbOKOnly, "Query Show"
'Actual INSERT
dbs.Execute " INSERT INTO tblMatchPlayer " _
        & "(MatchID, PlayerID, SubstituteID, PositionID, Surname, ScoreTime, RedCards, YellowCards, Substitude, Penalty, OwnGoal, Assist) VALUES " _
        & "(" & Me.MatchID & ", '', '', '', " & Me.cmScoreName1 & ", " & Me.tbScoreTime1 & ", '', '', '', " & Me.cbPenalty1 & ", " & Me.cbOwnGoal1 & ", " & Me.cmAssist1 & ");"

dbs.Close

End Sub
```

When the MsgBox pop-ups up to show me the Query it's going to write in the table I'm getting these results.

> INSERT INTO tblMatchPlayer (MatchID, PlayerID, substituteID, PositionID, Surname, ScoreTime, RedCards, YellowCards, Substitude, Penalty, OwnGoal, Assist) VALUES (29, '', '', '', Grozema, 34, '', '', '', 0, 0, Bruins);

I can't see anything wrong with this insert query.. however VBA does seems to think he is missing some parameters but I don't know what parameters.

The fields in my table are as this.

- MatchPlayerID - Autonumber
- MatchID       - Number
- PlayerID      - Number
- SubstituteID  - Number
- PositionID    - Number
- Surname       - Text
- ScoreTime     - Text
- RedCards      - Text
- YellowCards   - Text
- Substitude    - Text
- Penalty       - Yes/No
- OwnGoal       - Yes/No
- Assist        - Text

Can you guys help me out?

With kind regards,
Patrick

Comment: Is it accept null values?

Comment: Do you mean the empty field? or do you mean the Yes/No fields?

Comment: You probably make a typo with this field: `OwnGoals`. In your query you have `OwnGoal` - without s. Also, I am not sure if you can give empty string `''` as a `PlayerID` field if it is of Number type (the same with other fields, i.e. `SubstituteID`) - maybe try to change it to 0 instead of empty string.

Comment: Sorry my bad, thats a typo when I filled it in here. It's both OwnGoal
No joy, even if I give those fields a value of 0 it keeps saying the same error. :(

Comment: Another thing is that the last value: `Bruins` should be in quotations.

Comment: Okay, so now I have both names in quotations, `surname` and `assist` now I don't get the error to few parameters anymore but it isn't writing in the table as well...

Comment: [How to debug dynamic SQL in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1099570/3820271)

Comment: Never mind my reply from not working, I forgot to refresh my table :),  thanks for the help. it's working now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of viewing your sql statement in a MsgBox, debug.print it. Then copy it, create a new query, switch to SQL view and paste the statement as the SQL. Switch to design view and the problem will rear it's head.

Comment: Tnxs for the tip.
Use full for when something is broken again